# Set up a different db from default for FirestoreReactiveRepository

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with FirestoreReactiveRepository in a Spring Boot application. I followed the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.2.0.RC1/reference/html/#reactive-repositories) to perform the configuration, and the application is using "default" db from Firestore...for now everything is working as expected.

My question is, how can I use a different db for the current implementation?

I can't find any documentation or examples with this kind of configuration, I mean using a different one than "default" Firestore database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seems like there is a PR that fixes this issue, it just did not made it into the official documentation yet.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/pull/2164

There is now a property you can set in your application.yml (or application.properties) called `spring.cloud.gcp.firestore.database-id`, I tested it and it works as expected.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      firestore:
        database-id: test
```